# How to identify my device by their physical path?

Tags: udev, devices, paths

I'm creating a computer which manipulate harddrives.

I would like to identify the harddrive not by the order in which I plug them into my computer but by the slot I put them into.
I know Ubuntu (Linux/Udev) used to have a "by-path" sorting folder for persistent device naming. But it has been removed for a reason I don't quite understand.

I'm seeking help to somehow recreate a way to identify the physical path and therefore the slot I plug my harddrive into. I think through udev rules it should be possible but I don't know how they work.

Comment: Please provide more information on your hardware and software. The driver of de storage controller should be providing the path information. So please [edit] your question and provide details on the hardware and what you *do* see as device path information.

Answer (score 2):

The by-path for ATA devices was removed because it was possible for the same device to have multiple different by-path names.

There are a couple of options to get the physical path, including reading `/sys/block/`, asking `blkid`, querying `udevadm`, or querying `udisks`.

If you want a list of block devices with mountable file systems which are present, and don't want to use any extra libraries, then perhaps the simplest thing is:

```
udevadm trigger --dry-run --verbose --property-match=ID_FS_USAGE=filesystem
```

(this doesn't need any root privileges). If you want all block devices, then

```
udevadm trigger --dry-run --verbose --subsystem-match=block
```

will give a list, including device-mapper (and also loopback, etc...).

Source: [bug #1193705](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/systemd/+bug/1193705/comments/4)